# my alarmmanager sometimes not firing

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

my alarmmanager sometimes not firing

Main_activity:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp1.getCurrentHour());
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp1.getCurrentMinute());
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long timeDif = cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
long horaFinal = System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY + timeDif;
long result = (cal.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000;
long results = (horaFinal- System.currentTimeMillis())/1000;
long alarma;

if(result >= 0 && result < 60){
     alarma = cal.getTimeInMillis();
}else{
    alarma = horaFinal;
}

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Temporizador.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarma, pendingIntent);


    if (result >= 0 && result < 60) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "La alarma sonará en menos de un minuto.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (result < 3600 & result >= 60) {
        result = result / 60;
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "La alarma sonará en " + result + " minutos.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (result >= 3600) {
        int resultado = (int) (result / 3600);
        long minutos = (result % 3600) / 60;
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "La alarma sonará en " + resultado + " horas y "
                        + minutos + " minutos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }else{
       if(results >= 0 && results < 60){
           Toast.makeText(this, "La alarma sonará en menos de un minuto.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else if (results < 3600 & results >= 60) {
        results /= 60;
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "La alarma sonará en " + results + " minutos.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }else if (results >= 3600) {
        int resultado = (int) (results / 3600);
        long minutos = (results % 3600) / 60;
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "La alarma sonará en " + resultado + " horas y "
                        + minutos + " minutos.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();  
       }
    }
```

The "Temporizador" class I have the following:

```
package com.example.alarmarockfm;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Temporizador extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*Intent i = new Intent(this, EmisoraRadio.class );
        startActivity(i);*/     
        Intent i = new Intent(context, EmisoraRadio.class); 
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        context.startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

And finally, in my Manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarmarockfm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.alarmarockfm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name="Temporizador"></receiver>
         <activity android:name="EmisoraRadio"></activity>
         <activity android:name="Configuracion"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Usually works, but if my app is running in the background fails, or if the phone is  a long time locked

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this ? I am facing the similar issue, my alarm manager doesn't work when device is set idle (Not charging, Screen Off). This happens sometimes only and on some devices only. Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() instead of System.currentTimeMillis()

And also see this difference

ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP :trigger the alarm since boot time and 
  RTC_WAKEUP: trigger the alarm according to the clock time

Comment: Oks, I know when not work..  
If my phone enter in sleep mode, my app not working! What I can do?